# SpriteKit - Mouse Snaps to Center On Sprite Drag

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create an iOS game and I have it so that when the item is touched and moved it is dragged. When it is dragged the mouse is snapped to the center of the sprite. How could I make it so that this wouldn't happen?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4PDA.gif) is an example of what is happening.

Here are the functions dealing with touch input

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var papers = 0

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)

        if ((touchedNode.name?.contains("paper")) != nil) {

            touchedNode.position = location
            touchedNode.position.x = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
        }
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)

            if ((touchedNode.name?.contains("paper")) != nil) {

                touchedNode.position = location
                touchedNode.position.x = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
            }
        }
    }

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
        if ((touchedNode.name?.contains("paper")) != nil) {
            touchedNode.zPosition = 0
            touchedNode.position.x = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. `contains` is an extension off of the String class to check if a substring is in a string

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward to drag a sprite from the touch location instead of from the center of the sprite. To do this, calculate and store the difference (i.e., offset) between the touch location and the center of the sprite. Then, in `touchesMoved`, set the sprite's new position to the touch location plus the offset.

You can optionally overload the `+` and `-` operators to simplify adding and subtracting `CGPoint`s. Define this outside of the GameScene class:

```
func - (left:CGPoint,right:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: right.x-left.x, y: right.y-left.y)
}

func + (left:CGPoint,right:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: right.x+left.x, y: right.y+left.y)
}
```

In GameScene, define the following instance variable

```
var offset:CGPoint?
```

and then in `touchesBegan`, replace

```
touchedNode.position = location
```

with

```
offset = location - touchedNode.position
```

and in `touchesMoved`, replace

```
touchedNode.position = location
```

with

```
if let offset = self.offset {
    touchedNode.position = location + offset
}
```

I generalized the solution to offset the sprite's position in both the `x` and `y` dimensions. In your app, you can simply offset the sprite's `y` position since `x` is ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for a while!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need touchesBegan and touchesEnded for this. You can use just touchesMoved:

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
        let previousPosition = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

        if (touchedNode.name == "paper") {

            var translation:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: location.x - previousPosition.x , y: location.y - previousPosition.y )

            touchedNode.position = CGPoint(x: touchedNode.position.x , y: touchedNode.position.y + translation.y)


        }
    }
```

The idea is to calculate translation. You can read more about this solution [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites). For future readers Obj-C solution on StackOverflow can be found [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695061/3402095).