# Normalize touch location to offset the sprite (anchor point) position

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, offset, normalize

I'm trying to write a "normalizing offset function" to give the effect that when the user touches/moves the sprite, that it does not snap to the center of the touch (the default behavior). The offset function should probably address the anchor point during "touches began, and touches move", and then revert back to the center when touches ended.[enter link description here](http://www.iagnol.com/programming-slides/offset.png)

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

private var redSquare : SKSpriteNode?
private var originalAnchorPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Get label node from scene and store it for use later
    self.redSquare = self.childNode(withName: "redSquare") as? SKSpriteNode

}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  for touch in (touches ) {

    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    redSquare?.position = location
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches ) {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if (self.redSquare?.contains(location))!{

            redSquare?.position = location

        }
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    // set red sprite anchor position to originalAnchorPoint

}
```

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196599/spritekit-mouse-snaps-to-center-on-sprite-drag

Comment: Thanks. This looks good